# Binding Datetime to Textbox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have couple of tables in database with Datatype DateTime and default value getdate() in sql server. while I am binding this to textbox it is displaying 1/1/0001 as default. I am using Silverlight Ria services.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=LST_UPDT_TS, StringFormat=\{0:D\}}"/>
```

Thank you for helping and for ur time..

Comment: What format do you want? Have you researched [Silverlight stringformat](http://www.designersilverlight.com/2010/05/28/silverlight-4-binding-and-stringformat-in-xaml/)?

Comment: yeah i want the same string format

Answer (score 0):

The textbox is displaying the default value for DateTime, which means two things:

1. The Binding worked (else the TextBox would be empty).
2. The property `DateTime LST_UPDT_TS`... has not been set

You should check that the property is being set properly, and that you are binding to the correct instance.

Comment: tanq for ur reply.. i did check the binding but everything looks to be alright... But dont know y... it is displaying the date as 1/1/0001... If i enter the current date manually it is saving the same to the database and it is displaying the same date on relaoding again...but i want to add a new record the date is 1/1/0001... in my senerio date have to defaulty loaded...